Using multiple rest calls in angular in an atomic way
I'm learning Angular, Spring Boot and Hibernate at the moment and I found a good tutorial on that. But I have a problem where I can't find the answer. There are occasions where I have multiple REST calls to do and I can't combine them in a single one, e.g. I have to increment an amount in one call and to decrement the amount of another object in another (can also be on different servers/applications).
The solution I know so far is to call the API, subscribe it and if it succeeds to start the other API call. I could react on both results if there is an error like:
    this.sourceService.decrement( {
      body: this.decrementRequest
    }).subscribe( {
      next: (): void => {
        this.targetService( {
          body: this.incrementRequest
        }).subscribe( {
          next: (): void => {
            this.router.navigate(['/transfer/done']);
          },
          error: (err) => {
             this.router.navigate(['/transfer/done']);
          }
        });
      },
      error: (err) => {
         this.router.navigate(['/transfer/done']);
      }
    });

But when I do it this way, having an error in the targetService would lead to wrong data because the sourceService already did its job. It is also not advisable to call the sourceService again with a kind of "undo" because you don't know, if the failure also occures in this call.
So does anybody has a hint where I can find a tutorial explaining a pattern or methods/interfaces that I can use to make transactional REST calls?
Thanks in advance
Parascus

You can use switchMap, which switches to the inner API call, when the outer API call completes. This can be used to chain multiple API calls.
When the first API call fails, the switchMap does not execute.
 this.sourceService.decrement( {
      body: this.decrementRequest
    }).pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.targetService( {
          body: this.incrementRequest
        });
      })
    ).subscribe( {
          next: (): void => {
            this.router.navigate(['/transfer/done']);
          },
          error: (err) => {
             this.router.navigate(['/transfer/done']);
          }
        });


Hello Naren Murali, thanks for your reply. But still if the second service call fails the first one would still be executed? This is the problem I want to address because if the second call fails the first call has to be undone.

@parascus you should create a single api that does all the actions, if any failure rollback the database transaction, that is how to do it, if an api completes then there is no reverting back, so these kind of reverting actions should not happen on the frontend

Yes, that would be a solution if you are on one single server. But how for example is it done using payment systems like paypal. How is the handshake done? Because I can't combine the services always to one "big" service if the services are located on different servers in a micro service environment or third party servers are involved.

I just read in the related something promising that I will follow: Best practice to 'rollback' REST method calls inside method (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49225818/best-practice-to-rollback-rest-method-calls-inside-method?rq=1)

@parascus microservices can share code between them as far as I am aware, so you should share the code, apply the API calls in a single transaction and rollback if any failure happens
